# PHP do-while loop not working

Tags: php, while-loop, do-while

So I've been stuck on this do-while loop not working for about two hours. I really don't understand why it doesn't work. I'm getting this error:

`Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in /public_html/me/yes.php on line 60`

The only problem I think of is that it doesn't accept while loops in a do-while.

Here is my working code for just the inner while loop:

```
$maxcols = $numofcols-1; //=9
$maxrow = count($myarray)-1; //=44
$currentcol=0;
    $currentrow=1;
    //do {
    $collection->insert(array($title[$currentcol] => $myarray[$currentrow][$currentcol]));
    $currentcol++;
    while ($currentcol<=$maxcols){
    $newdata = array('$set' => array($title[$currentcol] => $myarray[$currentrow][$currentcol]));
    $currentcol--;
    $collection->update(array($title[$currentcol] => $myarray[$currentrow][$currentcol]), $newdata);
    $currentcol++;
    $currentcol++;

    }
    $currentrow++;

    //} while ($currentrow<=$maxrow);
```

If I uncomment the two line's "//do {" and "//} while ($currentrow<=$maxrow);" my program dies with the error I mentioned above. Is there something dead simple as to why it's breaking my code? Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

Line 60 is:

`$collection->insert(array($title[$currentcol] => $myarray[$currentrow][$currentcol]));`

Comment: What is line #60 in the above code? And the notice you posted above should not cause the program to _die_.

Comment: It's the very first line after the "do{" statement. Sorry!

Comment: @SalmanA Obvious question... That's what I was about to ask myself...

Comment: how many titles are there in the `$title` array?

Comment: 9 in total. The array goes from $title[0]-$title[8]

Comment: Well what the error message says is that you're trying to get `$title[9]`, which as you just said does NOT exist... What about trying to see what's wrong with your currentCol variable.... Maybe just add a check `if ($currentCol<9) {` then and only then, do... what's following...

Comment: Have you ever heard about `foreach`? This seems a C++ way of handling arrays. Take a look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The answer:

Such a simple little mistake, but there was no reset on the `$currentcol`

Moving the initialization down right below the do statement made it work correctly.Can you tell it's getting late? hahaha  Thanks all.

```
$currentrow=1;

do {
$currentcol=0;

$collection->insert(array($title[$currentcol] => $myarray[$currentrow][$currentcol]));
$currentcol++;
while ($currentcol<=$maxcols){
$newdata = array('$set' => array($title[$currentcol] => $myarray[$currentrow][$currentcol]));
$currentcol--;
$collection->update(array($title[$currentcol] => $myarray[$currentrow][$currentcol]), $newdata);
$currentcol++;
$currentcol++;

}
$currentrow++;

} while ($currentrow<=$maxrow);
```

Answer (score 1):

The inner while loop ends with `$currentcol` set to `$maxcols`. The next time you get there `$currentcol` has been increased by one (in the previous line) so it's `$maxcols+1`, so the while loop doesn't run. The next loop in the outer do loop now tries to access `$title[ $maxcols+1 ]` which is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`$currentrow` is initialized to the value `1`. If your array only contains one element, this has index `0`, so you're getting an "index out of bounds" error.

Also, you're determining the number of columns once globally (outside the `while` loop for the rows). Maybe you should determine the number of columns for each row just before you loop over the columns.

Also, you're not resetting the column index variable to 0, you just keep incrementing. Which causes an error in the second row, as you're starting out with a column index that doesn't exist.

Suspecting that PHP does not allow a while loop within a while loop is nonsense. Nested loops are a used very frequently - you just have to get the condition right

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
$maxcols = $numofcols-1; //=9
$maxrow = count($myarray)-1; //=44
$currentcol=0;
$currentrow=1;
do {
    if ($currentcol<9)
    {
         $collection->insert(array($title[$currentcol] => $myarray[$currentrow][$currentcol]));
         $currentcol++;
         while ($currentcol<=$maxcols){
             $newdata = array('$set' => array($title[$currentcol] => $myarray[$currentrow][$currentcol]));
             $currentcol--;
             $collection->update(array($title[$currentcol] => $myarray[$currentrow][$currentcol]), $newdata);
             $currentcol++;
             $currentcol++;
         }
         $currentrow++;
    }

} while ($currentrow<=$maxrow);
```

Comment: It does get rid of the error message but I very much doubt the script will work the way OP wants it to.

Comment: @Juhana I'm not sure about that too, coz it seems there's simply some logical error with the code. But let's just see...